# I can't call wildcard * in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards

I'm trying to make a program that removes files with "v" in their name

In my script I ask for a directory to look in. The code basically looks like this

```
read -p "directory: " DIRECT

rm *v* $DIRECT
```

It thinks `*v*` is the name of a file or directory and tells me there is nothing like it existing and it just jumps to `DIRECT` and says it can't be deleted.

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use 'find' instead of 'rm':

```
find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-D debugopts] [-Olevel] [starting-point...] [expression]
```

Your script would look like this:

```
read -p "directory: " directory

find "$directory" -name "*v*" -type f -delete
```

find checks if the Starting Directory exists and per default searches all subdirectories of that. If you don't want recursive search you have to add the option `-maxdepth 0` which limits the search to the starting directory only. In the example above I used the `-name` flag to search for filenames, but you could also use regular expressions (`-regex` option). As well you can limit the search by filetype (`-type` flag). For example `-type f` limits the search to regular files only. With the -delete flag you indicate, that you want to delete the found files.
If you need more options: `sh# man find` is your friend ;)

Answer (score 1):

That's not how `rm` works.  Try like this:

```
read -p "Directory: " SEARCH_DIR
if [[ -z "$SEARCH_DIR" || ! -d "$SEARCH_DIR" ]]; then
    echo "Error! Please enter a valid directory."
    exit 1
fi
rm "${SEARCH_DIR}/"*v*
```

`rm` is looking for a file in the last argument, and I would recommend always using a full or relative path when using rm especially with wildcards otherwise you are going to do some terrible things.

```
[root@JBCLAMP001 ~]# rm --help
Usage: rm [OPTION]... FILE...
```

You could also do something like this:

```
read -p "Directory: " SEARCH_DIR
if [[ -z "$SEARCH_DIR" || ! -d "$SEARCH_DIR" ]]; then
    echo "Error! Please enter a valid directory."
    exit 1
fi
for file in "$SEARCH_DIR/"*; do
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        if [[ $(basename $file | grep "v") ]]; then
            rm -f "$file"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: I'd also recommend adding some sanity-checking on `SEARCH_DIR` -- otherwise when someone isn't sure what to do and just presses return, it's going to try to delete everything at the root of the filesystem. It probably wouldn't succeed in deleting anything, but if it did it could be disastrous.

Answer (score 0):

The remove part could be changed to be:

```
read -p "directory: " DIRECT

( shopt -s extglob ; rm -f "$DIRECT/"+([!v]) )
```

The subshell *(…)* will avoid changing conditions for the running shell.

An alternative would be to use find:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '[^v]+' -type f -exec rm {} +
```

Answer (score -1):

To prevent `rm` from complaining that there is no file/directory matching `*v*` you should use the `-f` option. If those potential v-files are to be erased from `$DIRECT` you should do:

```
read -p "directory: " DIRECT

rm -f "$DIRECT"/*v*
```

This will not complain if nothing can be found to be removed (i.e. missing v-files, or even missing directory `$DIRECT`.